# Unknown test case error in C program

Tags: c

This a question I have to submit for an assignment, hence it has to be evaluated online. My program is running correctly for 6 out of 7 test cases. Only 3 test cases are provided and they are as shown:

**Sports or Economy Car**

Help Mr.Kamath to check whether his vehicle is an economy car or not. The program should display “There is a gas hog” if the mileage is less than or equal to 15 Km and the program should display “It is an economy car” if the mileage is not less than 30 Km. Otherwise display "Fuel Economy". Write a C program to get the values of a Car variables from the user. Create a structure called Car. Order of the  input values entered should be according to the structure variables

```
struct Car{
float startKm;
float endKm;
float litres;
};
```

**Test Case
Input 1**

```
30
50
5
```

**Output 1**

```
There is a gas hog
```

**Input 2**

```
40.5
80.5
1.5
```

**Output 2**

```
Fuel Economy
```

**Input 3**

```
30
0
5
```

**Output 3**

```
You have entered 0
```

**My code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Car 
{
    float startKm;
    float endKm;
    float litres;
};

int main()
{
    struct Car c;

    float m;

    scanf("%f",&c.startKm);
    scanf("%f",&c.endKm);
    scanf("%f",&c.litres);

    m=(c.endKm-c.startKm)/c.litres;

    if(c.startKm<=0||c.endKm<=0||c.litres<=0)
    {
        printf("You have entered 0"); return 0;
    }

    else if(m<=15) 
    {
        printf("There is a gas hog");

    }   

    else if(m>=30) 
    {
        printf("It is an economy car");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Fuel Economy");
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

**These are the test cases(unknown):**

[image: Image1]

**These is my evaluation output:**

[image: Image2]

PS: I am facing similar problems in many such programs with several test cases.

I also asked a similar question [Cannot identify error with code, failing a test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219796/cannot-identify-error-with-code-failing-a-test-case)

It would be helpful if someone suggests how to approach such unknown test cases.

Comment: Please don't post images of *text*, especially as links that can disappear. Instead copy-paste the text, verbatim and as-is, into the question body.

Comment: Suggest changing `c.endKm<=0` to `c.endKm<=c.startKm`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I need to check whether the inputs are 0 as per the required output

Comment: There is no need to return 0 on this line  `printf("You have entered 0"); return 0;` at that point it becomes confusing to the reader, it will exit at the bottom of the loop normally

Comment: So what result will you get from `c.startKm = 10; c.endKm = 5;`?

Comment: Maybe you should allow startKm=0

Comment: @WeatherVane I assumed for all inputs start<end, as my assignment questions tend to mention such invalid inputs. Added the condition to my code.

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller That was the failing test case. Thanks.

Comment: @AritraDasgupta never make assumptions about inputs. Better to use a catch-all.

Comment: those 'test cases' are actually just scenarios.   Test cases contain a list of input values and an expected output value(s)  Note: for each scenario, there are (at least) 2 test cases, for the upper and lower edge conditions, for values in the wrong order, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you should be able to start from 0 km. I went ahead and tried my own test case: 
Starting km 0, Ending km 25, Liters used 1

`if(c.startKm < 0 || c.endKm <= c.startKm || c.litres <= 0)`